# My OSQA users can't access their authentication settings after changing their password

Tags: python, django, osqa

A couple users complained that they couldn't get to their authentication settings page on OSQA. They receive a 500 error. [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq6Q9.png) But, it is only after they go through the "I Forgot My Password" or after changing their password.
Looking at the log, the error specifically is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable name 'name' referenced before assignment
```

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, how do I fix it.
Thank you in advance for your help.!!

The Stack Trace from the log reads as follows (Sorry for the poor formatting):

```
DIRECTORY/forum/templatetags/extra_tags.py TIME: 2012-12-13 09:23:31,419 MSG:extra_tags.py:render:312 Error in declare tag, when evaluating:    questions.children_count('answer')
DIRECTORY/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py TIME: 2012-12-14 12:40:31,086 MSG: base.py:handle_uncaught_exception:209 Internal Server Error: /osqa/account/9/authsettings/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DIRECTORY/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "DIRECTORY/apps/osqa/forum/views/auth.py", line 348, in auth_settings
    'name': name,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment
DIRECTORY/apps/osqa/forum/views/meta.py TIME: 2012-12-14 12:40:31,093 MSG: meta.py:error_handler:200 
        error executing request:
        PATH: /osqa/account/9/authsettings/
        USER: USER (1)
        METHOD: GET
        POST PARAMETERS:
            None
        GET PARAMETERS:
            None
        HTTP HEADERS:
            mod_wsgi.listener_port: 8080
    HTTP_REFERER: URL/osqa/users/9/USER
            mod_wsgi.listener_host: 
    SERVER_SOFTWARE: Apache
        SCRIPT_NAME: /osqa
        mod_wsgi.handler_script: 
    SERVER_SIGNATURE: 
    REQUEST_METHOD: GET
    PATH_INFO: /account/9/authsettings/
    SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
    QUERY_STRING: 
    HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
    HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive
    HTTP_COOKIE: sessionid=REDACTED; csrftoken=REDACTED
    SERVER_NAME: SERVERNAME
    REMOTE_ADDR: SERVERIP
    mod_wsgi.request_handler: wsgi-script
    wsgi.url_scheme: http
    PATH_TRANSLATED: DIRECTORY/apache2/htdocs/account/9/authsettings/
    SERVER_PORT: 8080
    wsgi.multiprocess: True
    mod_wsgi.input_chunked: 0
    SERVER_ADDR: SERVERIP
    DOCUMENT_ROOT: DIRECTORY/apache2/htdocs
    mod_wsgi.process_group: 
    SCRIPT_FILENAME: DIRECTORY/apps/osqa/scripts/osqa.wsgi
    SERVER_ADMIN: you@example.com
    wsgi.input: <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x46feab0>
    HTTP_DNT: 1
    HTTP_HOST: SERVER:8080
    wsgi.multithread: False
    mod_wsgi.callable_object: application
    REQUEST_URI: /osqa/account/9/authsettings/
    HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    wsgi.version: (1, 1)
    GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
    wsgi.run_once: False
    wsgi.errors: <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x487c4f0>
    REMOTE_PORT: 51455
    HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.8
    mod_wsgi.version: (3, 3)
    mod_wsgi.application_group: localhost:8080|/osqa
    mod_wsgi.script_reloading: 1
    wsgi.file_wrapper: <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x47bf0a8>
    CSRF_COOKIE: REDACTED
    HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate,sdch

    COOKIES:
             csrftoken: REDACTED
    sessionid: REDACTED

    EXCEPTION INFO:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "DIRECTORY/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "DIRECTORY/apps/osqa/forum/views/auth.py", line 348, in auth_settings
        'name': name,
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Do you have any means to dump more information to the log? A stracktrace would probably help you in finding the bug.

Comment: Please do not include `csrftoken`'s and `sessionid`'s in a public website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `osqa`, here's what can be found around the lines where you're having an issue (the line numbers differ from yours, but that's probably due to a version difference):

```
347     for k in auth_keys:
348         provider = AUTH_PROVIDERS.get(k.provider, None)
349
350         if provider is not None:
351             name =  "%s: %s" % (provider.context.human_name, provider.context.readable_key(k))
352         else:
353             from forum.authentication.base import ConsumerTemplateContext
354             "unknown: %s" % ConsumerTemplateContext.readable_key(k)
355 
356         auth_keys_list.append({
357         'name': name,
358         'id': k.id
359         })
```

Looks like at line 354, we should have `name = "unknown: %s" % ConsumerTemplateContext.readable_key(k)`, but someone forgot that `name =`.

I can't be 100% sure about this, as I am not really knowledgeable in `osqa`, but this statement doesn't do anything otherwise if we leave it like it is. Additionally, your bug is 100% reproductible provided you can identify why `k.provider` isn't in `AUTH_PROVIDERS`, which I guess has to be *pretty* uncommon.

---

You might want to [file a bug at `osqa`'s bug tracker](http://jira.osqa.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa). To solve your issue in the shorter term, you could:

- Figure out why your `provider` is `None`. (Apparently, the issue caused by there being and `auth_key` for the current `user` that doesn't correspond to any of `AUTH_PROVIDERS`).
- Fix that line in the code yourself.

Comment: So, what change would I have to make if I wanted to fix the line? Just add the "name ="? Also what file would this be in?

Comment: it's in `osqa/forum/views/auth.py` (it's in your traceback ;) ). You should preprend `name = ` to the line that says `"unknown: %s" % ConsumerTemplateContext.readable_key(k)`. What you have might be different from what I posted, as I don't know which version of `osqa` you're running.

Comment: @ChrisPowell Will you have a look at the `osqa` bug tracker to figure out if the issue has already been reported, and report it otherwise? I think this could benefit the community of `osqa` users!

Comment: And viola! That has fixed the problem! I just filed a bug report. :)

Comment: @ChrisPowell That's great! : )